"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'elapsedTimeActual')" Integration Procedure
I am trying to fetch a dataraptor data using integration procedure.when I am removing the "file" field of data type BLOB Integration Procedure shows correct data.But after adding field "file" it gives the error - "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'elapsedTimeActual')" in IP. DR is working fine in either case.
Can anyone please let me know what might be the issue?

Click on setup--> search for omni Interaction configuration --> Create a New Omni Interaction Configuration as following:
This solved my issue.

